# Hyperledger Fabric state-based endorsement using nodejs

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to set the key-level endorsement policy in my nodejs chaincode.

I can successfully set the endorsement using the following code

`await ctx.stub.setStateValidationParameter(dataID, Buffer.from("OR('Org1MSP.client','Org1MSP.admin','Org1MSP.member')");`

I am using first-network default configuration. The problem is that when I want to update my data I get "ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE" error. The docker logs shows the following error. stateBasedValidator.Validate failed, err validation of key data1 (coll'':ns'monitoring') in tx 6:0 failed: Error unmarshaling to SignaturePolicy: proto: can't skip unknown wire type 7

Without setting the statebased I can successfully update my data, which means the problem comes from the way I set sate-based endorsement policy.  I could not find any example regarding state-based endorsement using nodejs and I am not sure my ep format is correct.

Comment: I think there is typo in setting up quotes in the policy. Could you please try something like this: `Buffer.from("OR('Org1MSP.client','Org1MSP.admin','Org1MSP.admin')");`

Comment: @ChintanRajvir Thank you for pointing this out. I actually made the typo mistake in my question here. In my chaincode code,  I input policy as you mentioned and still the problem exists. I fix the question.

Comment: @ethertest I am also facing same issue, did you manage to fix the issue ?

Comment: Try this, import { KeyEndorsementPolicy } from 'fabric-shim'; const ep = new KeyEndorsementPolicy(); ep.addOrgs('MEMBER', ...ownerOrgs); await ctx.stub.setStateValidationParameter(assetId, ep.getPolicy());